What's wrong with wrapping NavHostController in a wrapper class and injecting it to dependency injection?
Let's say I have a class
data class Navigator(val navController: NavHostController)

And I inject it to koin/hilt.
class MyViewModel(private val navigator: Navigator): ViewModel(){} // using koin

Advantage -
Let's say i have
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(toSettings: () -> Unit)

fun NavGraphBuilder.home(toSettings: () -> Unit)

NavHost() {
    home() { /* navigation logic */ }
}

and I want to navigate to profile screen too. So now I have to change three places
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(toSettings: () -> Unit, toProfile: () -> Unit)

fun NavGraphBuilder.home(toSettings: () -> Unit, toProfile: () -> Unit)

NavHost() {
    home(toSettings = {}, toProfile = {})
}

but if I had access in my ViewModel, I wouldn't need to. I haven't seen this approch in any place. Is there something wrong with this

How do you instantiate a NavHostController?

@Chris since we will be using singleton object of Navigator, we can instantiate it while implementing NavHost.
Injecting it in MainActivity(not in constructor parameter but in fields) and instantiate it using rememberNavController

Add the code to the question. If you use a Context to instantiate a NavHostController, what happens when the context used to instantiate the NavHost has gone because of some lifecycle change or configuration change? Think about the lifetime of the objects to determine if it's a good idea or not. Your VM will outlive the view it's attached to, so try not to have any view related objects (such as those instantiated with a Context) as a constructor property of the VM.
